# How to force iscsid to reconnect target?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, iscsi

I have installed open-iscsi, and have login to several targets. The device is mounted, and doing some IO. 
But I want to disconnect the tcp connection of initiator and target, force iscsid to run recovery and reconnect. 
How to do this? 
I have used tcpkill to kill some tcp connection, and iscsid will run recovery and reconnect to target. But i don't know which tcp connection belongs to which target. So if i want to reconnect target1, I may kill the tcp connection of target2.
How to identify the tcp connections to targets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your targets have different IP addresses, you can use netstat, and grep for port 3260 (iscsi).

```
$ netstat -nap | grep 3260
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 172.16.10.16:48471          172.16.10.201:3260          ESTABLISHED -
```

Then use tcpkill on the local port and destination IP:

```
$ sudo tcpkill -9 -i eth1 "port 48471 and host 172.16.10.201"
```

If your targets don't have different IP addresses, it looks like the best way is to increase the logging level of iscsid to **2** so that you can see this message that's logged when it makes a connection.

```
 log_debug(1, "connected local port %s to %s:%s",
           lserv, conn->host, serv);
```

There doesn't appear to be another way to get the initiator-side port out of iscsid.

Comment: Finally i have added a command in iscsiadm to get the src ip and src port of some connection.